# post an image to firebase using requests

Tags: python, firebase, python-requests, google-cloud-storage

I use requests to post an image to firebase but I have problems with the link which is meant to post in, I've tried several links it tells me: unauthorized of this link does not exist on the site.

I don't want to use the Firebase Admin SDK or any other module. I would like to do it using requests.
I would appreciate it if anyone could be of assistance.

**Below is my code**

```
    def load_list1(self, path, filename):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        self.sampleimage.source = filename[0]
        self.params = {"sample1": open(filename[0], "rb")}
        self.getimage = requests.post("https://console.firebase.google.com/project/moonlighting-bb8ab/storage/moonlighting-bb8ab.appspot.com/files~2FTemitayoAdefemi?token=" + app.idToken, files = self.params)
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with `google-cloud-firestore`, but you seem to be trying to upload an image to `google-cloud-storage`. The two are completely separate products, and you'll have the best chance at getting help if you use the correct tag.

Comment: The URL you're using in your code points to the Firebase console, which is not a public API to upload data to Google Cloud Storage. To learn to how to upload to Google Cloud Storage from Python, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api and specifically this section on authenticating your requests https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication. I also recommend checking some of these results for tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+google+cloud+storage+ReST+API